# There is no row at position 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to execute this code in getting an error as

> There is no row at position 2"

How can I solve this?

```
public JsonResult Question()
        {

            try
            {
                string [] Question=new string[2];

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString: "Server = (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb; Database = QuestionDb; Trusted_Connection = True; MultipleActiveResultSets = true");
                con.Open();
                string query = "";
                query += @"select Id,Sum(Yes) AS T_Yes,Sum(No) AS T_No,Sum(DontKnow) AS T_DontKnow from dbo.Questions Group By Id";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

                
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter cmd1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                cmd1.Fill(dt);
                
                    if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
                    {

                        Question[0] = "0";
                        Question[1] = "0";
                        Question[2] = "0";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Question[0] = dt.Rows[0]["T_Yes"].ToString();
                        Question[1] = dt.Rows[1]["T_No"].ToString();
                        Question[2] = dt.Rows[2]["T_DontKnow"].ToString();
                    }
                
                    return Json(Question);
```

Comment: You need to add rows to the DataTable using dt.Rows.Add()

Answer (score 1):

You're checking only to row count = 0, try this:

Also for comentary answer you need all data for the pie chart so need to recover all records.

Add a reference to System.Data, System.Collections.Generic and System.Linq to your project if this does not compile

```
List<string[]> listofIdGroups;
        List<string[]> listofIdGroups;
        listofIdGroups = dt.Rows.OfType<DataRow>()
            .Select(dr => new string[3] { dr["T_Yes"].ToString(), dr["T_No"].ToString(), dr["T_DontKnow"].ToString() }).ToList();
```

you can read the list this way:

```
        foreach (string[] question in listofIdGroups) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yes:" + question[0] + Environment.NewLine + "No: " + question[1] + Environment.NewLine + "DontKnow: " + question[2]);
        }
```

try it here:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/0S1N3c

Comment: -1


I have build a web application for questionnaire having 6 questions with three radio buttons each , when the user click on any of the button that should be saved in database and sum up all the three columns i.e Yes No Dontknow (radio buttons) and display in a pie chart for the dashboard.

Comment: Then you need something completely diferent, I'll edit the answer

Comment: I need to get from database table which i have created in my asp.net mvc core after the questions survey i need a pie chart to be displayed according to customer answers

Comment: you are grouping by  Id in your SQL query, so if you have diferent IDs you'll get a list of sums

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are mixing rows and columns. Use:

```
Question[0] = dt.Rows[0]["T_Yes"].ToString();
Question[1] = dt.Rows[0]["T_No"].ToString();
Question[2] = dt.Rows[0]["T_DontKnow"].ToString();
```

You must use always dt.Rows[0] (instead of [1] or [2]) to get the properties of the first row.